# Conservation of chirality in non-weak elementary particle interactions

Tags: standard-model, elementary-particles, chirality

Chirality is not conserved in propagation (e.g., electron oscillates between left and right chiral). But is chirality conserved in interactions? What is a good reference paper or book for this notion of chiral conservation (or not) in interactions?

As an example, in QED Bhabha scattering say a left-chiral electron and a right-chiral positron interact, both being annihilated and thereby creating a virtual photon which after propagation an electron and positron are then created. Is the newly created electron required to be left-chiral (as opposed to right-chiral or a superposition of chiralities)? Likewise for the positron and its right-chirality?

As a side note, I'm not concerned about how we know the initial electron and positron are purely left and right chiral, respectively. As a theoretical question, I'm presuming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any good QFT book would spend lots of space on vector-like (~nonchiral) interactions such as QED & QCD, and then contrast them to chiral ones for the weak interactions. I gather you are cool with the [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabha_scattering) sample calculation.

The basic vertices are equal mixtures of both chiralities,
$$
eA_\mu \overline \psi \gamma^\mu \psi = e A_\mu \overline \psi _R \gamma^\mu \psi_L +eA_\mu \overline \psi_L \gamma^\mu \psi_R  \\ = e A_\mu \overline {\psi _L} ~\gamma^\mu \psi_L +eA_\mu \overline {\psi_R} ~\gamma^\mu \psi_R 
,
$$
so in the t-channel (exchange) an electron or positron emitting or absorbing a virtual photon preserves its chirality.

In the s-channel (annihilation &  creation), as you say, the annihilants have to have opposite chiralities, and the products as well. The two types of diagrams add and interfere. The virtual photons are off-mass-shell, so like massive.

The completeness relations $ \sum_{s=1,2}{u^{(s)}_p \bar{u}^{(s)}_p}  = {p\!\!/} + m $ involve the fermion masses, so contaminate/violate chiralities, in principle, proportionally to *m*, which you monitor doing your traces.

(If you used helicity amps, instead, you'd note that in the center of mass of the annihilants, the spin-1 rotation matrices would favor emission of the creation products in the direction of the original helicities, in a telltale $1+\cos\theta$ distribution. So at right angle emission, you've *lost memory of the original helicities*, and basically also chiralities, since helicity and chirality are mismatched by *m/p*.)